# Getting chrome driver version compatible with chrome browser

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium

I am using selenium wevdriver to read javascript href, I need to get the version of the browser with chrome driver automaticly.
how to fix it?

here I'm putting the version in application.properties which would make headache if chrome updated

```
ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().version(chromeDriverVersion).setup();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();              
driver.get(URL);
```

Comment: As far as I know there the web driver is not included in the Chrome browser.

Comment: No, I tried to use it's in python

Comment: @AliOuda The second answer to that question is for Java